# Minimum necessary files (CLI) for Bazaar

Tags: windows, command-line, installer, bazaar

Is there a way to repackage Bazaar to include only the commandline tools (`bzr.exe`, etc.), similar to the non-Tortoise version of Mercurial? What are the minimum files needed, if possible?

If it already exists, though, where can we download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on the Bazaar Q&A site: [Using Bazaar on Windows without Admin privileges](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/116456)

It provides a link to where a [self-extracting archive](https://launchpad.net/bzr/2.0/2.0.0) can be downloaded (see the `bzr-2.0.0-1-nonadmin.exe` file). At the bare minimum, it allows use of the CLI tools for Bzr. Hopefully they put out something for v2.1.1, but this one will work for what I need.

---

At the Bazaar mailing-list, it was suggested that running the installer and zipping up the extracted files into a self-extracting archive should work. So far it seems to be working fine.